# Why I cannot open a excel file copied from a network location?

Tags: networking, microsoft-excel

I have a file on the network, if i right click and copy it from the network and paste it on C:\localdata\username\theFolder once i disconnect off the network and double click to open the file, it opens a blank workbook. WHY?

Comment: If I were to hazard a wild guess based on the limited information I know about your system configurations, it would be that your system is configured not to trust files located on the network.

Comment: All files on network is trusted. Once i disconnect off network, I've set excel to allow files trusted in the location of where i left the file at.

Comment: How are you opening the file?  Are you opening Excel then opening the file or are you dragging and dropping the file into Excel, or are you double-clicking on the file?  Edit your question.

Comment: Post has been edited.

Comment: Does the file have links to *other* documents that are only available when connected? Are you perhaps copying a *link* to the file, rather than the file itself?

Comment: It's uncommon behaviour,, I guess one possibility may be the Copied File is part of process as intermediate file and since you are opening it out of the original Folder so that unable to populate Data !! Tell me while you open, is the Excel re-directs you to File Open Dialogue Box?

Comment: there's no links in document and it does not open in file open dialogue, it opens as a new blank workbook.

Comment: Does it open the workbook and all the cells appear to be empty? Or does it open the workbook and no cells are appearing at all (just a grey background)? OR does it open a completely NEW workbook?

Comment: completely new blank workbook.